# Change the order of columns for a custom post type on the admin list page

Tags: custom-post-types, screen-columns

I have created a custom post type (screen shot below), and would like to change the order of columns. Is it possible to move the "tags" column before the "date" column?

Screen shot:

[image: Screen shot]

Comment: Your image link is broken

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes this is possible. I have changed this for the default post type, but this is also possible for a custom one.

First check the codex:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/manage_posts_custom_column

```
function your_columns_head($defaults) {  

    $new = array();
    $tags = $defaults['tags'];  // save the tags column
    unset($defaults['tags']);   // remove it from the columns list

    foreach($defaults as $key=>$value) {
        if($key=='date') {  // when we find the date column
           $new['tags'] = $tags;  // put the tags column before it
        }    
        $new[$key]=$value;
    }  

    return $new;  
} 
add_filter('manage_posts_columns', 'your_columns_head');
```

You can change the $defaults array as you like this way.

Comment: You can skip setting `$tags` as you don't return it or use it elsewhere.

Answer (score 4):

Yes You can change the order of your list shown in Admin Panel. First you have to unset the default array after that make array of your choice let me show with example
The following image show custom post type default field.
[image]

Now let me show you how you can remove some extra field from this list. Suppose i want to remove the title and tags field from the list and add my custom post type field and also rearrange the order of list fields

```
     function add_ourteam_columns ( $columns ) {
    unset($columns['title']);
    unset($columns['tags']);
    unset($columns['date']);
   return array_merge ( $columns, array ( 
     'name' => __ ('name'),
     'designation' => __ ( 'Designation' ),
     'image'   => __ ( 'Image' ),
     'date' => __('Date')
   ) );

 }

add_filter ( 'manage_our-team_posts_columns', 'add_ourteam_columns' );
```

[image]

If you want to remove the field just use unset(field_name), if you want to change the order of the list first unset that field then make a new array and add that field after or before other field. I hope this example would help you

Comment: thanks man :). helped me lot :)